# What does this forever loading behavior tell us?

Tags: web-application, sql-injection

I have a form with just `username` and `password` fields. Now as usual I entered this `" or 1=1 --` query in `username` field and just gave a random `password`. And then the page kept loading forever until `This site can't be reached` error popped up.

[image: this site can't be reached]

**note**: This pic is random pic from google images.

Now why I ask this question is I have seen this behavior pretty often (or at least in quite a few website which I have tried to pen test). While the page kept loading on new tab the website was working as normal unlike this page.

What is the reason for this 'forever loading'? Is it because it is trying to print the database or something else? And what does this mean? (Is website vulnerable to this attack?)

sorry if this question has been asked(I didn't do much research)

Comment: Your request could automatically be getting rejected and the connection being dropped- since the data in the form was identified as being malicious by some network traffic monitoring utility.  Also, if you were given permission to pentest the target you should also be able to work with the owner of the website to investigate the error from their perspective.

Comment: Yeah, it's propably the waf blocking the connection.

Comment: The image is not of "forever loading" but of a closed connection

Comment: @schroeder I did not mean literal "forever loading". I meant it kept loading for quite a long time and then this closed connection message showed up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your request could automatically be getting rejected and the connection being dropped- since the data in the form was identified as being malicious by some network traffic monitoring utility (for example, a web application firewall).

Also, if you were given permission to pen test the target you should also be able to work with the owner of the website to investigate the error from their perspective.

(Copied from my comment made on the original question)

Answer (score 2):

The reason depends on how the login query is structured internally. It doesn't necessarily mean it is retrieving all the entries in the table (it could be).It could also mean the query is causing the database to return an error message which is unhandled by the application or it handles it in such a way that no response is returned to the client.
In any case, the answer is yes, the website is most likely vulnerable to SQL injection, but this doesn't mean your particular query is working.

Comment: SecretSasquatch's answer is also another possibility, that could also certainly be the behaviour of a WAF as well.